# Copy each row n times

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy every row 12 times from sheet1 to sheet 2.

Right now I copy the first row 12 times but row 2 is only copied once. I have provided a sample of the sheet and my code. Hope you guys can help.

My data starts in row a13

As a bonus I need to transpone the values in columns E:P

The reason why I need to do this is because all values in E:P is the value for each month and the values in A:C is the attributes that is necessary to identify the values in month to a certain car with year, registrations number and service

```
Sub copyEachRow()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 12
    Sheets("asheet1").Range("A13").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("sheet2").Cells(i + 13, "a") 
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]
[image: Bonus!!]

Comment: You need nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Transpose

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyEachRow()
    
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A13"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A13"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(sFirst).CurrentRegion.Value
    
    Dim rCount As Long
    rCount = UBound(Source, 1)
    
    Dim Dest As Variant
    ReDim Dest(1 To rCount * 12, 1 To 4)
    
    ' Write headers
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 3
        Dest(1, j) = Source(1, j)
    Next j
    Dest(1, 4) = "Value"
    
    ' Write body.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
        For n = 1 To 12
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To 3
                Dest(k, j) = Source(i, j)
            Next j
            Dest(k, 4) = Source(i, 3 + n)
        Next n
    Next i
    
    ' Destination Array to Destination Range.
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, 4)
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        .Resize(k).Value = Dest
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: amazing! after a few modification it fits like a charm :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyEachRow()
    Range("A1:C32").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim I As Long
Dim xCount As Integer

xCount = 11

For I = Range("A" & Rows.CountLarge).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
Rows(I).Copy
Rows(I).Resize(xCount).Insert
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt this piece of code to your need:

```
Sub copyEachRow()
    Dim cel As Range
    With Sheet2
        For Each cel In Sheet1.Range("A13", Sheet1.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            cel.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(12)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

just place a header in Sheet2 column A cell after which you want to paste data from